# AVR-GCC Makefile - multiple targets

Tags: c++, makefile, avr-gcc

I'm creating a group of ATMega devices with different programs. They share lot's of files like classes.

I want to create a makfile that will contain something like:

```
DEVICE1DEPS = first.o second.o thrid.o
DEVICE2DEPS = second.o thrid.o fourth.o
...
```

Then I want to be able to write **make device1** and have

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I./ -o device1.out $(device1deps)
```

I also have a rule called **program** to write my program on chip
I want to be able to write **make device1 program** / **make program device1** to execute

```
avrdude -p t2313 -c dapa -e -U flash:w:device1.hex
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can make two `program` targets: `program1` and `program2`, and make them depend on `device1` and `device2` respectively. Then when you `make program1` you will also invoke `device1` automatically.